# Regex pattern to match emails inline reply heading

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having a little trouble figuring out the pattern to identify the beginning of inline replies/forwards in an email body, there are some easier ones that simply begin with something like "Begin forwarded message" but the replies are a little more complicated:

```
On 12-06-13 10:56 AM, "John Doe" <john.doe@some.tld> wrote:
```

Obviously the constants will be "On" and "wrote:".  I'd like to be able to find only the first match and then either wrap everything after it in a div with display:none applied or even just eliminate it using substr($body,0, POSITION_OF_MATCH).

One of the issues I'm having is that it's not catching the FIRST occurrence, and second is that I can't get the greediness to work properly.

My progress (having fallen back to at least a partially working version) so far is:

```
preg_match("/On [^>]* wrote:/i",$content,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you're not capturing anything in there. there's no `()` to trigger capturing.

Comment: It was indeed matching though, I was getting the entire matched string, as well as the offset as expected, the only problem was that it was missing the first match. The offset was all I needed to use substr().

Comment: To: Mr./Ms. Anonymous: Not sure what the -1's are for, I spent a fair bit of time researching and trying to find the answer on my own, there weren't any questions on SO that I could find dealing with email reply strings, and I posted examples.  Guess I can't please everyone. Meh.

Comment: downvotes of a fact of life. people should say why they're doing one, but it's not required (and no, I didn't downvote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the other answers, but none of them really took into account the many possible variations in the reply strings I was dealing with, that might have been my fault for not explaining properly or providing more options.  I've +1'd everyone for their efforts though.

The final solution which seems to be working best after a day of fiddling with it on and off is this:

```
/On (Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|[[:digit:]]{1,2})(.*?) wrote:/i
```

The option list that it begins with covers a range of different reply types that start with "On Tue..." or "On 23..." or "On 1...", etc. ensuring that the greediness I was complaining about wasn't taking in too much from random "on" strings elsewhere, the (.*?) takes care of the rest of the name/email portion, finally following up with "wrote:" to finish it off.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how your current version works at all, because you cannot possibly match the closing `>`. But you could do something like this:

```
$content = preg_replace('/(On [^>]*> wrote:).*$/s', '$1', $content);
```

Which will match the first `On ... wrote:` and everything after that up until the end of the string. And replace it by just the `On ... wrote:`.

Comment: +1 for preg_replace and the capture of everything to the end, once I've fine tuned all of the different patterns I'm trying to capture, this will definitely be part of the endgame.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably break this down by elements; so you basically have:

```
On DATE, "NAME" <EMAIL> wrote:
```

You can then characterize `DATE`, `NAME`, and `EMAIL`.

- `DATE` is composed of numbers, dashes, spaces, colons, and letters. However, it ends with a comma, so you can use that instead.
- `NAME` is composed of letters and spaces, though it is delimited by quotes, and you can probably handle that.
- `EMAIL` is a bit more complicated, but emails cannot contain the character `>`, so you should be able to capture everything but that.

So you basically get:

```
On [anything but comma], "[anything but "]" <[anything but >]> wrote:
```

Which, in regex, is something like:

```
/^On ([^,]+), \"([^\"]+)\" <([^>]+)> wrote:$/
```

Then, when using `preg_match`, you can get your matches from some `$matches` array, indices 1 through 3.

Comment: It's a great start, however I've found variations where the date is represented with "Wed, Jun 13, 2012" which as you can see has two additional commas, not including the trailing one that deliniates the Name.

Comment: Changing that to `(.*)` should be okay, because the next group is determined by the `"` following the first group.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest

```
$email = preg_match('/^On [^"]*"[^"]*" <([^>]*)> wrote:$/', $str, $re) ? $re[1] : '';
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/9Icti9).